# MySQL - How to refer to server as http path?

Tags: mysql

I am trying out WebIssues [link text](http://webissues.mimec.org/) which allows for a client-server issue tracker.
I have setup the MySQL database required.

The problem is that the client program wants a 'Server URL' in order to connect to the database.

Normally on my network I just refer to the servername and/or databasename.
How do I provide a http style path to the MySQL database for the client program to recognize?

My server is called 'John' and the database is called 'webissues'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

webissues is a web-based application. they also have a windows front-end that requires the web front-end to be installed. the windows front-end asks for the URL to the web front-end because that is how it access the data.

Comment: Thanks.
I had to use http://John/webissues/index.php
AND had to ensure that 'Connection' parameters under 'Settings' were not set.

Answer (score 2):

Asking for a "server URL" is very odd, but possibly it may want you to use some variation on this form:

```
protocol://username:password@server.dom:port/database
```

The `username:password@` is valid, if little-used, URL syntax that you might see around specifying usernames and passwords for HTTP basic auth or FTP.

Answer (score 1):

You could just feed it an ip address as a URL, for exactly http://192.168.1.101/  Or you could turn the server's name into a URL http://servername/  With out knowing how your network is set up, it's hard to tell exactly how to make it work.

As a side note, you might consider moving this question to serverfault.com.  That's where the networking and server folks tend to hang out.  We're just programmers here ;)

Comment: I try to be 'just a programmer' but somehow I have ended up managing 7 servers in geographically dispersed locations!....must be because they are running 'my' programs...